# How to estimate weights for summation of variables

Tags: regression, weights

I have scores of two people, for which I want to create a combined score. This combined score is what I use as an independent variable. Currently I weigh both scores equally, so 50/50. But I have incentive to believe the scores for the first players are more important, so I want to be able to weigh them differently to get a combined score.

How can I estimate these weights, to obtain a combined score which may be different than just 50/50?

Comment: The first player score is important for what? Is the combined score used as a dependent variable for another model, for which you think more accuracy is gained by increasing the first player score? If so, this is a natural place to use regression. Fit your player scores to a regression based on some test data, and the coefficients will represent the relative importance of each score.

Comment: No, I think the player score of the first player may be more important for determining the combined total score. I want to use the combined total score as an independent variable for modelling purposes.